# Android FRAGMENT 'requestFeature must be called'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am having trouble trying to use 'requestFeature' in my FRAGMENT. My code is below, I am trying to set the actionbar as an overlay.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I do not want to use a theme because I don't want the whole app to be effected, only this fragment in particular.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `requestWindowFeature()` before the `setContentView()` in the Activity's `onCreate()` method. This Activity is the one that your fragment is a part of.

Comment: that doesn't do anything. I even tried setting the value in styles but nothing.

Comment: by moving the requestWindowFeature() into onCreate of Activity should help you stop the app crashing. Right?

Comment: Yes it did. But when it does work.. won't it set the actionbar overlay for all fragments?

Comment: The action bar overlay is tied to the activity or the window and not to the fragment instance. Does that make sense?